# Intermittent Failures when Jenkins runs Capybara/Cucumber tests with Selenium Webdriver in headless state

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, jenkins, cucumber

I have a jenkins server that is running my cucumber tests whenever i push a commit. Is there any known issues where jenkins running selenium will cause intermittent errors? All the tests pass consistently on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

There is no well known issue with Jenkins that causes intermittent error when running tests. It is in fact as stable as your test suit is.

I would start looking for differences between the environments. Are there any external services that are unstable and causes your issues?